# Deep linking whatsapp inside cordova-Phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, whatsapp

I'm building a cordova phonegap application on Android and I'm trying to enable the user to share through whatsapp. According to the Whatsapp FAQ the following code should work:

```
 <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello">CLICK</a>
```

But it does nothing. How could this be? THank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must add it as a whitelist intent (config.xml)

```
<allow-intent href="whatsapp://*" />
```

Make sure you have cordova plugin installed
**cordova-plugin-whitelist**